# uncheck and check checkboxes when clicking dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html

I want to removed the checked checkboxes when clicking the dropdown and check a checkboxes on the dropdownlist. for example I have this code

```
<input id="item-1" type="checkbox">item1</input>
<input id="item-2" type="checkbox">item2</input>
<input id="item-3" type="checkbox">item3</input>

<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="1,2">check the item 1 and 2</option>
   <option value="1,3">check the item 1 and 3</option>
   <option value="1,2,3">check the item 2 and 3</option>
</select>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$('#dropdown').live("change", function() {
    //remove all the chekced checkboxes
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    //check chekboxes
    var selected = $('#dropdown :selected').val();
    dataitem = selected.split(',');
    $.each(dataitem, function(key, item) {
        $('#item-' + item).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

What happened here is that when i add this code

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

it will removed all the checked chekboxes but it will not add when I select on a dropdownlist. but when I removed that code it will check a checkboxes but it will not removed on the previous checked checkboxes.

Comment: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/9DCAs/, tell me again and more specific what you want to do?

Comment: here is something wrong: <option value="1,2,3">check the item 2 and 3</option>. 1,2 and 3 or just 2 and 3???

Comment: Your problem is really strange, when inspected with Chrome, the DOM is updated as expected, but ticks are not rendered using the latest jQuery. With older versions it works just fine. I have just replaced your `live` with `on`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work just fine to me, I just noticed that `<option value="1,2,3">` was inconsistent with the text and changed it to `<option value="2,3">`.

See: http://codepen.io/AlienHoboken/pen/knCHh

Comment: weird its working on that example code you gave. but here on my actual code, it is not. Sorry for "check the item 2 and 3" it should be "check the item 1, 2 and 3

Comment: sorry guys! its working now! I don't know what happened lately because its not working! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
      <input id="item-1" type="checkbox">item1</input>  
      <input id="item-2" type="checkbox" value="item2">
       <input id="item-3" type="checkbox" value="item3">

     <select id="dropdown">
       <option value="1,2">check the item 1 and 2</option>
        <option value="1,3">check the item 1 and 3</option>
      <option value="2,3">check the item 2 and 3</option>
     </select>


     $('#dropdown').live("change", function() {
     //remove all the chekced checkboxes
     $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        //check chekboxes
     var selected = $('#dropdown :selected').val();
     dataitem = selected.split(',');
     $.each(dataitem, function(key, item) {
           $('#item-' + item).attr('checked', true);
         });
     });
```