# Disable dropdown list when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My View code in MVC: I want to disable the Dropdownlist in View code when the checkbox is checked.

```
function SaveNewGroup() {

    var group = RetrieveGroup();
    var IsChecked = $(IsAssociation).is(":checked");
    var url = (IsChecked) ? "/Administration/SaveNewGroupforIsAssociation" : "/Administration/SaveNewGroup";
    var userID = $('#groupunderwriter').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: group,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (groupID) {
            if (groupID > 0) {

                GetGroups();

                $('#groupdialog').dialog('close');
            }
            else {
                alert("Unable to create Group.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Check box:

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <label>Is Association</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type ="checkbox" id="IsAssociation"/>
            </td
```

>
        
and my dropdownlist:

```
<tr>
<td>Underwriter Name:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="groupunderwriter" style="width:150px;">
                <option value ="0"></option>
               @foreach (RMS.UserService.User u in Model.GroupUnderWriters)
                {
                    <option value="@u.UserID">
                        @if(Model.MasterGroupAttribute.UserID == u.UserID)
                   {
                       @:selected="selected"
                   }
                   >@(u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName )</option>

                }
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
```

How to disable the dropdownlist when the checkbox is checked or enable it when not checked?

Comment: Check [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337473/uncheck-and-check-checkboxes-when-clicking-dropdown-list?rq=1), this is the exact opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle. It works fine for me. i don't know why all the above are not working for you. I just used the jQuery ON event listener in case you have a race condition and these elements don't exist when you are creating a binding for them. Unlikely but hey, my example works. This isn't the ideal way to do it but it may give you some insight as to whatever is wrong with your code.

```
<input type ="checkbox" id="IsAssociation" /><span>your checkbox</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="groupunderwriter" style="width:150px;">
   <option value ="0">Hello</option>
    <option value ="1">Goodbye</option>
</select>

$(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('#groupunderwriter').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#groupunderwriter').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T83vs/

Comment: no problem, it's not the ideal way but I had a feeling you were bringing before the element existed and jQuery 'ON' will solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

A short version would look like this:

```
$('#IsAssociation').change(function() {
    $('#groupunderwriter').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Where did you put the code? If you put it in the header, before the body, you have to wrap it between `$(function() { --code here-- });` so it runs after the dom is loaded. I updated the answer so it uses the selectors from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any checkbox there, Anyway this is the simple jquery code to disable dropdown on checkbox checked.

```
$(function() {
  $('#id_of_your_checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // disable the dropdown:
        $('#id_of_dropdown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#id_of_dropdown').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `prop` is a better way to do it.

```
$("#groupunderwriter").prop("disabled", IsChecked);
```

Of course you can also use `$("#checkbox").is(":checked")` instead of `IsChecked`.